# how to find candidates by date "findByDate"

Tags: java, spring-boot

My problem is that I can not get the candidates by date, in my code I used a controller and a repository as following

1- CandidatController

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/api")
   public class CandidatController {

      @Autowired
      CandidatDao candidatdao;

      @GetMapping(value = "/GetAllCandidats")
      public List<Candidat> listeDesCandidat(){

          List<Candidat> candidats = candidatdao.findAll();
          return candidats;
      }    
      @GetMapping(value = "/GetAllCandidats/{date}")
      public List<Candidat> afficherCandidat(@PathVariable ("date") 
                      @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date date) {

          return  candidatdao.findByDate(date);
      }
```

2- CandidatDAO

```
  @Repository
  public interface CandidatDao extends JpaRepository <Candidat, String>{

    List<Candidat> findByDate(Date date);
   }
```

3- classcandidat

```
  @Entity
  public class Candidat {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name = "candidat_id")
     private int id;

     private String nom;
     private String prenom;
     private String ville;
     private int numTel;
     private String mail;
     private String pseudo;
     private String roleCible;
     private String typeContrat;
     private String villeRecherchee;

     @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
     private Date date;
```

in a browser the result is:
with(http://localhost:8080/api/GetAllCandidats/)

```
 {
id: 1,
nom: "Sar",
prenom: "Samir",
ville: "tissemsilt",
numTel: 76676810,
mail: "kira.DJ@gmail.com",
pseudo: "FET",
roleCible: "INGENIEUR",
typeContrat: "CDI",
villeRecherchee: "NANTES",
techno: [ ],
date: "2019-04-16",
secteurActivites: [ ]
},
{
id: 2,
nom: "xxxx",
prenom: "yyyyy",
ville: "zzzzzz",
numTel: 76676810,
mail: "kira.DJ@gmail.com",
pseudo: "FET",
roleCible: "INGENIEUR",
typeContrat: "CDI",
villeRecherchee: "NANTES",
techno: [ ],
date: "2019-04-22",
secteurActivites: [ ]
},
```

But with (http://localhost:8080/api/GetAllCandidats/2019-04-22), the result is null:

```
[]
```

Comment: `Date` as in date or timestamp (in the database?). If it is the latter it will probably not match as it included time, and hence no results. If you really only want a date change add `@Temporal(DATE)` to your field to only store the date (and change the column accordingly).

Comment: I used [@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date ] and the date type on my database is "Date" but the result is still null

Comment: The result isn't `null` it is an empty list.

Comment: Yes, Is Empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I request you to kindly look this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date)

I suggest you to use the following code as per referring to the blog post.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```

Comment: I used [@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) private Date date ] and the date type on my database is "Date" but the result is still null

Comment: See in application.yml properties you have added SQL Dialect for hibernate or not.
Alternatively..
Drop the table once, and then execute the code JPA will again create the table. 
I wish then I might work..

Comment: i not add sql dialect but, the result is still empty,

Comment: Debug the code, It might be the problem with mapping